# VSCode debug Node.js with ES6 unhandled error in debug adapter

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to debug a Node.js program which is coded with ES6.

I use babel to compile the ES6 to ES5, and everything works fine, code works fine when I run it without debugging.

When it comes to debug, a problem shows up.

There are 3 files:

index.js

```
import hello from './imported';
import hello2 from './imported2';

const h = hello();
const h2 = hello2()

console.log(h);
console.log(h2);
```

imported.js

```
function hello() {
    return 'hello world';
};

export default hello;
```

imported2.js

```
function hello2() {
    return 'hello world again';
}

export default hello2;
```

and here is my launch.js

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 5858
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/index.js",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

yes, I am using source map, so that the breakpoints can stop at the source file.

I put 3 breakpoints in the program:

1. index.js `const h = hello();`
2. imported.js `return 'hello world';`
3. imported2.js `return 'hello world again';`

When I enable all 3 breakpoints, all breakpoints works fine, when I disable the first breakpoints, something wrong happens, debug console prints:

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because Node.js v8.5.0 was detected.
node --inspect=38607 --debug-brk build/index.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38607/7cf119cf-beb5-4105-84f3-880f44c9fe00
Debugger attached.
hello world
hello world again
******** Unhandled error in debug adapter - Unhandled promise rejection: Error: not opened
    at LoggingSocket.send (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:219:16)
    at LoggingSocket.send (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/vscode-chrome-debug-core/out/src/chrome/chromeConnection.js:43:20)
    at Client._sendQueuedRequests (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:82:30)
    at Client._send (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:76:14)
    at Promise (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:100:18)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client.call (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:98:16)
    at Proxy.target.(anonymous function) (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:140:53)
    at NodeDebugAdapter.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/nod[...]
******** Unhandled error in debug adapter - Unhandled promise rejection: Error: not opened
    at LoggingSocket.send (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:219:16)
    at LoggingSocket.send (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/vscode-chrome-debug-core/out/src/chrome/chromeConnection.js:43:20)
    at Client._sendQueuedRequests (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.node-debug2/node_modules/noice-json-rpc/lib/noice-json-rpc.js:82:30)
```

It seems the program works fine, but the breakpoints do not take effect.

How could I make the breakpoints works when I just enable the last two breakpoints?

I am using:

- Visual Studio Code Version 1.16.1 (1.16.1)
- node -v v8.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34615

for a quick look, here is the key:

> If you set the outFiles property of your launch config to point toward those files on disk, then it should be able to load the sourcemaps ahead of time.